# How to save Exif data after bitmap coppression in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I need to get image from sd card, create, rotate and save changed image.
I try to use this code

```
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    ExifInterface originalExif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
    int orientation = originalExif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    int rotate = 90;
    if(orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90){
        rotate = 180;
    }else if(orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180){
        rotate = 270;
    }else if(orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270){
        rotate = 0;
    }

    matrix.postRotate(rotate);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(original, 0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        original.recycle();
        bitmap.recycle();
    }


    ExifInterface newExif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());

    newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90));

    newExif.saveAttributes();
```

But i cant save change in ExifInterface. This just clear all the tags.

Comment: what exactly you want ? image rotation based on exif data or your want to save your data in exif ?

Comment: This seems a good example: https://github.com/apache/commons-imaging/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/imaging/examples/WriteExifMetadataExample.java#L221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saveAttributes method only Save the tag data into the JPEG file.

check this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#saveAttributes()

So if you change your code this

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

to this

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

it will save you exif tag data

Hope this help

Let me know in case of any other issue

Comment: @couldDog I am glad, If you find my answer helpful please accept my answer so other too get help from here  thanks

Comment: @couldDog is my answer is what you need or other thing have you tried that works for you because you still havent accepted my answer

Comment: I do not know that i must accept answer a question. Now i know this and i had clicked on check. Thanks.

Comment: No it does not save EXIF.