# ANDROID - Writing EXIF Data

Tags: java, android, exif

I'm trying to write EXIF metadata to the pictures that were taken using my App. However, it displays an error saying:

> E/JHEAD﹕ can't open '/sdcard/Pictures/CameraApp/IMG_20151205_133506.jpg'

I'm trying to write the EXIF metadata using the following codes:

```
public void loc2Exif(File file) {
    try {
        ExifInterface ef = new ExifInterface(file.getCanonicalPath());
        Log.i("LOCATION", String.valueOf(latitude) + " " + String.valueOf(longitude));
        ef.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, dec2DMS(latitude));
        ef.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE,dec2DMS(longitude));
        if (latitude > 0)
            ef.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "N");
        else
            ef.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "S");
        if (longitude>0)
            ef.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "E");
        else
            ef.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "W");
        ef.saveAttributes();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
static String  dec2DMS(double coord) {
    coord = coord > 0 ? coord : -coord;  // -105.9876543 -> 105.9876543
    String sOut = Integer.toString((int)coord) + "/1,";   // 105/1,
    coord = (coord % 1) * 60;         // .987654321 * 60 = 59.259258
    sOut = sOut + Integer.toString((int)coord) + "/1,";   // 105/1,59/1,
    coord = (coord % 1) * 60000;             // .259258 * 60000 = 15555
    sOut = sOut + Integer.toString((int)coord) + "/1000";   // 105/1,59/1,15555/1000
    return sOut;
}
```

Below are the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: why are you give permition two time WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: have you tried with my answer in this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753634/how-to-save-exif-data-after-bitmap-coppression-in-android/33780787#33780787 ?

Comment: why people go out after asking the question do force someone to give negative marking